# Php sort mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

I want to sort a table by click on the header. Once I click it, the table is sorted A->Z. Next time I click it, it should be sorted Z->A. I don't know what is wrong. Every time I click the header, the second part of the condition is activated.

I deleted the previous code and paste the almost solution with the usage of $_SESSION.

```
if (isset($_SESSION['sorted']))
{
    if($_SESSION['sorted']== 1)
    {
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT filename, address, id FROM $tablename order by ".$column." DESC");
        $_SESSION['sorted'] = 0;
        echo "sorted = ". $_SESSION['sorted'];
    }
    else
    {
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT filename, address, id FROM $tablename order by ".$column);
        $_SESSION['sorted'] = 1;
        echo "sorted = ". $_SESSION['sorted'];
    }
}
else
{
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT filename, address, id FROM $tablename order by ".$column);
        $_SESSION['sorted'] = 1;
        echo "isnotset.sorted = ". $_SESSION['sorted'];
}
```

Now it's working but with one problem. When the user refreshes the page, the $_SESSION variable is set to another value, as if the user clicked on the header again (pushing F5 sorts the table again and again).

Comment: global !== persistent, you need to store the current sort asc/desc in persistent storage

Comment: Just a guess: if you initialize $AZ_sorted = false, does it always sort the other way?

Comment: Is the page being reloaded each time the header is clicked?

Comment: Mark: You mean, should I store this variable in another table or file?
Scott: If I initialize as true, the first part of the conditional is activated.
j08691: I don't think so. I think only the query runs.

Comment: You could store the variable in the $_SESSION space.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are always setting `$AZ_sorted` to `true`. You should instead obtain it from the request, and set it to `true` only if it is not set. The details depend on how the rest of your site is structured. If you use a GET parameter for example you would need something like:

```
$AZ_sorted = $_GET['AZ_sorted'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Where are you setting $AZ_sorted to true?  I'm assuming this is being executed every time the page is loaded and resetting $AZ_sorted to true every time?

As an aside, global variables are never a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Because when you reload the page, $AZ_sorted is again initialized to TRUE, so it always goes to the else part of your conditionals statement.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not create the function sort($column) because it's a restricted function in php.

Otherwise, your setter seems not working :

```
$AZ_sorted = false;
```

try to replace true/false by 0/1 like this :

```
$AZ_sorted = 1;
function new_sort($column="") {
global $AZ_sorted;
if ($AZ_sorted == 0)
{
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT filename, address, id FROM $tablename order by ".$column);
    $AZ_sorted = 1;
    echo "$AZ_sorted = true";
}
else
{
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT filename, address, id FROM $tablename order by ".$column." DESC");
    $AZ_sorted = 0;
    echo "$AZ_sorted = false";
}
}
```

Comment: I have tried this. I set $AZ_sorted in the main code, not in the function, and I don't think the whole code is run when I click the header (why would it, anyway).

Comment: try to execute twice new_sort($column=""), you will see that the each part of the condition are executed.

Comment: what? execute twice? at first its 1. So at first the else is active, it is order by DESC and is 0. If i click again, the if should be active, it is ordered by ASC and is 1. Then the else is active again. This is how it should work, by reading this code, but it doesn't